Understanding entanglement
I’m probably missing something obvious. I'm new to physics, so please bear with me. Imagine flipping a perfect coin in a vacuum. The moment we through it up it splits exactly in half, with both halves having the same mass, velocity, and shape. Both halves likely go up in opposite directions and spin similarly before landing identically. They both always land head or both land tail.
This thought experiment brings me to entangled particles. Like the two halves of the coin, wouldn't entangled particles, having the same or related wave function, always display connected properties regardless of distance due to their shared origin?
What differentiates entanglement from the coin analogy, and how does it demonstrate non-local realism in the universe?

Does this answer your question? Quantum Entanglement - What's the big deal?

Hi Curious. Please use the search function next time before asking a question. Indeed, questions like this (which are reasonable and important) have been asked before here a thousand times, see e.g. the above link and the links therein.

Thanks for suggested duplicate, i’ll try to make sense of answers of the other question.
